# App store url is opening in safari but it is not opening in chrome.What could be the issue?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-chrome, safari, app-store

I have an app store button on my website which is opening app store app url.That url is opening in safari browser with app store but the same url is not opening in chrome.

I have tried to use other app urls also to check if it the issue with my app's url or not, but i am facing same issue with all app urls.

What could be the issue here? I have checked all available resources to fixed this but none of them worked for me.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: did you try https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142834/creating-a-url-that-always-opens-in-chrome ?
and here is official docs https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/ios/links

Comment: Can you post a link to your website?

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov Yes i have tried that but it's not working for me.

Comment: @pajevic Url is : https://www.gotourneyinc.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try appending `?mt=8` to your App Store URL like so:

```
https://apps.apple.com/in/app/gotourney-mobile/id1470734298?mt=8
```

The parameter `mt` stands for "media type" and tells the OS what they are dealing with. In this case, media type `8` indicates "Mobile Software Applications".

Comment: It is working in safari but not working in chrome. In chrome it is just opening that url in browser.

Comment: It is working fine in Chrome for a test I have done. Where have you tried it? On the website you have provided the url is stil missing the `mt` parameter.

Comment: I have added mt=8 parameter now, but still the same issue it is working for safari but not for chrome. You can check it here: https://www.gotourneyinc.com/

Comment: It's working now.The issue was with target="_blank".I have removed that and it is working fine now.

Comment: Just getting "Cannot connect to App Store" on Chrome for iOS like always. I don't have `target="_blank"` either. On Safari for iOS the link works fine, as always. I wonder if it's because my app is "Unlisted"...